# C - How to trace this recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

I've been looking at examples of recursion (in C) online in an attempt to get a better understanding of it and how it works. Generally speaking, I can trace some basic recursion problems without issue (such as a factorial problem), but I found this one and am completely lost on how to trace it.

The idea is that you have the user enter an amount of change, and by using recursion, you print out the number of ways that amount of change can be made. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_DENOMS 4

int ways(int amount, int denomination);

int main()
{
    //Declarations & initializations
    int userChange = 0;

    //Get user input
    printf("Enter an amount you wish to get change for (in cents):\n");// get the amount of change in from the user
    scanf("%d", &userChange);

    //Function call... pass user's input and denomination values (ints) as parameters
    printf("%d cents can be made in %d different ways\n", userChange, ways(userChange, NUM_DENOMS));

    return 0;
}

//Function to find # of ways to make change for user's amount
int ways(int amount, int denomination)
{
    static int validAmounts[NUM_DENOMS] = {1, 5, 10, 25};

    if(denomination<=0) //if denomination is invalid
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if((amount == 1) || (amount == 0)) //base case: only 1 combination
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(amount < 0) //can't have negative amount of money
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else //if denomination is valid and user's change > 1
    {
        return ways(amount, denomination-1) + ways(amount-validAmounts[denomination-1], denomination);
    }
}
```

Apparently this is a common application of recursion. I can't wrap my head around how this recursion works though. What stands out to me the most is the fact that there are 2 recursive calls on the same line. I have never seen recursion applied in this way.

I did attempt to trace it but my results are definitely wrong:

Say I enter 25 as the amount of change. When I go into the `ways` function, none of the base cases are satisfied and so the recursion comes into play. For the first call, `amount` stays the same and `denomination` is decreased by 1, so we go back into the function with 25 and 3 (4-1) as our new arguments. None of the base cases are met until `denomination` is reduced to 0 (since `amount` never changes). At this point, we are returning 0. This is the point where I get lost. I see it that 0 gets sent back through all the previous calls and so the end result is 0, but that doesn't sound right to me. I run into the same problem when trying to trace the second call except instead of 0 getting sent back through the calls, it is 1. Obviously my perception of this recursion is horridly wrong. Can someone explain to me how this instance of recursion actually works?

Comment: step through it in a debugger, then you'll see.

Comment: FYI, using 2 or even 3 recursive calls on the same line is normal.

Answer (score 1):

One way to trace a recursive algorithm is to put a `printf` at the top of the recursive function. The `printf` should print out the arguments to the function. It's also a good idea to temporarily add more parameters to give yourself additional information about what the recursion is doing. The most common additional parameter is a `depth` parameter that shows how many nested calls have been made. And for this particular question (where you have two recursive calls) I would add an additional parameter to identify which call is being traced.

With that in mind, here's the modified code. I suggest starting with a simple input, like `5`, to get a feel for how the recursion works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_DENOMS 4

int ways(int amount, int denomination, int left, int depth);

int main( void )
{
    int userChange = 0;

    printf("Enter an amount you wish to get change for (in cents):\n");
    scanf("%d", &userChange);

    printf("%d cents can be made in %d different ways\n", userChange, ways(userChange, NUM_DENOMS, 'M', 0));

    return 0;
}

int ways(int amount, int denomination, int left, int depth)
{
    static int validAmounts[NUM_DENOMS] = {1, 5, 10, 25};

    printf( "%2d %d %c %2d\n", amount, denomination, left, depth );

    if(denomination <= 0 || amount < 0)
        return 0;

    if((amount == 1) || (amount == 0))
        return 1;

    return ways(amount, denomination-1, 'L', depth+1) + ways(amount-validAmounts[denomination-1], denomination, 'R', depth+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code makes two calls because it breaks the problem into two parts and each part is solved the same way. Each part is in some sense simpler than the original problem and the same method is used to solve each individual problem. As pointed out by others, there may be situations in which there are more than two parts.

You have likely seen examples with one call where one part of the problem is solved and the single recursive call solves the 'remainder' of the problem.